# SyntaxError when trying to pip install pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

When i type in python 3.6.5 shell:

```
import pip
pip install pyautogui
```

it returns this:

```
>>> pip install pyautogui   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

in cmd it returns this:

```
>>> pip install pyautogui
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pyautogui
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

if i dont import pip it says this:

Python 3.6.5 shell

```
>>> pip install pyautogui
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

cmd (with python on path)

```
 >>> pip install pyautogui
 File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pyautogui
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So what do i need to do?

'install' is no command of pip.
What? everyone says yeah write pip install pyautogui. tadaaa.

Edit------------------------------------------------------------
It worked when i put pip in my path and then run the command. (In cmd of course)

Comment: Is `pip` in your PATH?

Answer (score 2):

`pip` should be used in shell command prompt, not in python prompt

Open the `cmd.exe` program from your windows and type the commands there.

The pip.exe is not in the same folder as python - it is installed in the `Scripts` subfolder so you have to navigate to that folder or add it to the `PATH` too.

```
C:\> CD \Python36\Scripts
C:\Python36\Scripts> pip install pyautogui
```

Or wherever your python is installed

Comment: I tried to use cmd.exe in windows but it didn't work but i could try the other thing

Comment: It will work i think, thanks